# $_POST only triggers once. How can i continuously listen for and process input from a button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am basically just trying to make a very simple page that will increment a number every time I press a button. So far I can increment it once, but after that nothing happens! The variables stay the same.

```
<?php
    include "test.php";
       
    if(isset($_POST['test'])){
        incVar();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="test" value="Increment Variable">
</form>
    
<?php printVars(); ?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Code inside "test.php"

```
$var = 1;

function incVar(){
    global $var;
    $var += 1;
}

function printVars(){
    global $var;
    echo $var;
}
```

The current output is just

"1"

after the first click of the button, it increments to "2" but then after that, the clicks do not increment the variable further.

Comment: You can use session or cookies to maintain state across requests

Comment: It won't work when you literally hardcode the value as `$var = 1;` because each time this PHP script is run, it will reinitialize the variable. Use one of the suggestions to make the value of the variable dynamic.

Comment: @El_Vanja Ohhh okay. I am very new to PHP and didn't understand it was running the entire script again. I used sessions and initialized it using !isset for the session variable. Thanks for the help guys!!!

Comment: Every request you make is a brand new request. PHP doesn't remember anything from the previous request unless you store it some where (like in a session, database, file or similar).